# Firebase function isn't realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a firebase query setup in a VueJS method

```
data: {this.todaysEvents}, 
methods : {
    getTodaysEvents (day) {
      this.todaysEvents = []
      const events = db.ref('calendar')
      const query = events.orderByChild('day').equalTo(day)
      console.log(query)

      query.on('value', snap => {
        this.todaysEvents.push(snap.val())
        console.log(this.todaysEvents)
      })
    }
```

This is then used via `v-for` loop:

```
<ul class="events-header-list">
    <li :key="index" v-for="(event, index) in todaysEvents[0]" class="chip">{{event}}</li>
</ul>
```

The issue comes when I update an event. The data doesn't sync realtime. What needs to happen to make this realtime?

EDIT: Here is the data returned by `todaysEvents`:

```
[
  {
    "Same Event": {
      "calendar": "Sports",
      "color": "orange",
      "date": "2017-05-22",
      "day": 23,
      "desc": "test description",
      "name": "test"
    },
    "some key": {
      "day": 23,
      "month": 6,
      "name": "cooler event"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with vue.js yet, but it seems that it's not detecting that you updated the data. This page seem relevant to that: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Is the result of `snap.val()` an array?

Comment: @BertEvans Firebase returns objects unfortunately.

Comment: What is `todaysEvents[0]`?

Comment: @BertEvans So since firebase returns an object and then I push that object of objects to the array `todaysEvents`  I then have to specify `[0]` to access the returned firebase object. I know there should be a way to transform this into an array using some `forEach` but I'm still figuring out JS.

Comment: Can you post the structure of what is returned? In your `console.log` does `this.todaysEvents` show a value?

Comment: @BertEvans it returns an array with 1 object inside with many objects inside that object: `[Object {Object, Object, Object}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147490/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-auzy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work, this came down to updating the way the callback was managing the values returned from Firebase.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    todaysEvents: [],
  },
  firebase: {
        test: db.ref('calendar')
    },
  methods : {
    getTodaysEvents () {
      const events = db.ref('calendar')
      const query = events.orderByChild('day').equalTo(23)

      query.on('value', snap => {
        let events = snap.val()
        let newEvents = []
        for (let key of Object.keys(events))
          newEvents.push(Object.assign({}, events[key], {key}))
        this.todaysEvents = newEvents
      })
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() =>
      this.getTodaysEvents(), 500)
  }
})
```

Comment: You can even do this using `forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a `value` observer to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single snapshot which you can then loop over to access individual children. See [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

You can also do it like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    todaysEvents: [],
  },
  firebase: {
        test: db.ref('calendar')
    },
  methods : {
    getTodaysEvents () {
      const events = db.ref('calendar')
      const query = events.orderByChild('day').equalTo(23);

      query.on('value', snap =>{
          snap.forEach(childSnap => {
              var childVal = childSnap.val();
              this.todaysEvents.push(childVal);
          });
      });


    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() =>
      this.getTodaysEvents(), 500)
  }
})
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/6sk7qt1z/)